# jQuery - drag-and-drop visual feedback on draggable clone

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, clone, draggable, droppable

Using droppable to provide feedback is not a good option due to their deeply nested structure (using greedy), so I would like to give visual feedback by changing the draggable (i.e., the clone).

Is this possible?  Has anyone done this in jQuery?

I've not seen any examples and I'm unclear on how to achieve it.  I've tried the over/out events, but that doesn't seem quite right as they seem get called on mouse move.

Any advice, particularly a sketched example, is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revisited over/out events and that worked:

```
over: function(event, ui) {
  c = ui.helper
  c.css('background-color', '#eeeeee')
},
out: function(event, ui) {
  c = ui.helper
  c.css('background-color', 'transparent')
},
```